# horizontal Progress Bar с иконкой, которая двигается вместе с ползунком

Tags: android, progress-bar

Как добавить иконку в horizontal Progress Bar? Она должна двигаться вместе с ползунком.

Comment: Не совсем понятно, вы хотите что то вроде SeekBar?

Comment: Да, то что нужно. Спасибо